# Get Child's Parent record

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named Category and fields named ID, ItemCode, ParentCode, FullName

I want the record to be something like this

```
CategoryCode   Child,     Parent
01             Meat       NULL
02             Red Meat   Meat
03             White Meat Meat
```

I able to get the parent and child records using this query but if a record does not have any parent it does not shows up.

```
SELECT 
C1.ItemCode, C1.FullName AS Child, C2.FullName AS Parent

FROM Category C1, Category C2 
WHERE C2.ID = C1.ParentCode
```

Comment: You are using an implicit inner join, switch to 'modern' `join` syntax, and use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thank you that worked @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @HoneyBadger

```
SELECT 
C1.ItemCode, C1.FullName AS Child, C2.FullName AS Parent

FROM IMM.tbl_ItemCategory C1
LEFT JOIN IMM.tbl_ItemCategory C2 ON C2.ID = C1.ParentCode
```